# Product of a null set

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $E \subset \mathbb{R}^m$, $F \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mu$ the Lebesgue measure.

How to prove:

If $E$ is a Lebesgue null set of $\mathbb{R}^m \Rightarrow E \times F$ is a Lebesgue null set of $\mathbb{R}^{m+n}$.

I know there is a way to show that implication with the theorems of Fubini, Tonelli and Cavalieri, but how can it be proved without them?

I used:

Since $E \times F$ is a rectangle, by definition: $\mu_{m+n}(E \times F)=\mu_m(E) \cdot \mu_n(F)$.

So if $\mu_m(E)=0\Rightarrow \mu_{m+n}(E \times F)=0$

Is this way correct? And how can it be shown if $\mu_n(F)=\infty$?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Doesn't matter whether $\mu_n(F)=\infty$, because by definition in this context $0\cdot\infty=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: consider $F_k = F \cap \prod_{i=1}^n [-k,k]$.  From you definition of product measure, $\mu(E\times F_k)=0$.  Apply the regularity of measure and let $k\to+\infty$ to conclude.